# How many nonces on average do I need to try in order to get n leading zeros?

Tags: mining-theory, proof-of-work

Assuming 256-bit hash output, how does the (average) number of nonces I need to try (to solve the proof-of-work puzzle) grow with the number of leading zeroes required, *n*? Is there a bound on this number?

Answer (score 2):

If you want n zeroes when written in binary, 2<sup>n</sup>.

If you want n zeroes when written in decimal, 10<sup>n</sup>

If you want n zeroes when written in hexadecimal, 16<sup>n</sup>.

If you want n zero bytes, 256<sup>n</sup>.

However, none of these things are relevant in terms of Bitcoin. The difficulty is not the number of zeroes required; the difficulty is the minimum ratio between a well-defined maximum value, and the hash you got (when interpreted as a 256-bit unsigned integer).

In practice, the formula is that you need difficulty * 2<sup>48</sup> / 65535 attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I  think that you need on average difficulty * 2<sup>32</sup> trials to solve the proof-of-work puzzle. Cf [the bitcoin specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty).