# Finding Hash with 11 leading zeroes

Tags: hash, proof-of-work, nonce

For an exercise, I'm trying to find a sha256 hash with 11 leading zeroes.

For this reason, I wrote a Python script that basically tries all intergers from 1 to N and brute forces the hash. Now my N is at 16^11.

Am I mistaken or is there a problem with my code as there must be a nonce somewhere between 1 and 16^11 where the hash has 11 leading zeroes?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Why must there be? And are you sure you really did 17 trillion SHA256 hashes? What do you mean by "brute forces the hash"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did 1.1 Trillion and found no 10. But I guess there is a flaw in this logic the longer I think about it.

Comment: 11 leading zeros in binary or hexadecimal?

Comment: @bordalix hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

Every attempted a hash has an *independent* probability of *1* in *16<sup>11</sup>* of having 11 leading zeroes.

That means a probability of not finding such a hash after *n* attempts is equal to the probability that *n* attempts are all unsuccesful: *(1 - 16<sup>-11</sup>)<sup>n</sup>*

That means the probability that you are successful increases with *n*, but never reaches *1*:

- *1%* chance after *176,807,378,144* attempts (*~16<sup>9.34</sup>*).
- *5%* chance after *902,361,177,698* attempts (*~16<sup>9.93</sup>*).
- *20%* chance after *3,925,582,869,332* attempts (*~16<sup>10.46</sup>*).
- *50%* chance after *12,193,974,156,573* attempts (*~16<sup>10.87</sup>*).
- *80%* chance after *28,313,531,182,477* attempts (*~16<sup>11.17</sup>*).
- *95%* chance after *52,701,479,495,622* attempts (*~16<sup>11.40</sup>*).
- *99%* chance after *81,015,010,678,098* attempts (*~16<sup>11.55</sup>*).
- *99.9%* chance after *121,522,516,017,148* attempts (*~16<sup>11.70</sup>*).
- ...

Answer (score 0):

No,the "nonce" could be alternate.Not limited in 1 to N.
But the expect time of finding a target hash is 16^11,that meaning if u try 16^11 different "nonce" u are likely get a target.

Answer (score 0):

> there must be a nonce somewhere between 1 and 16^11 where the hash has 11 leading zeroes [in fixed-length hexadecimal encoding]?

1. You cannot assume this.
2. Bitcoin doesn't encode in hexadecimal and then test for number of leading zeroes. The test it uses is literally `if (hash <= hashTarget)`

As you probably know, for current `hashTarget` values, miners expect to exhaust all nonce values and vary other block values such as the so-called "extranonce" etc - and retry many many times.

---

See

- [How many nonces on average do I need to try in order to get n leading zeros?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/60426/13866)

> you need difficulty * 2<sup>48</sup> / 65535 attempts.

Also note that's on average. You might never find one. The probability of finding a sufficiently small hash after n attempts is never 100% for any finite n.